# How to stop audio for every ajax call?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have a problem when dealing on audio play via javascript because sometimes it randomly play that unable to stop but need to destroy session. The current implementation on the ajax was called every 1sec..

I also using cookies to save session but it doesn't exceed to 4kb as it appends my data to generate audio sound.

my code:

```
function refreshPage(){

    var transaction_id = '';
    var form_data = { 
        transaction_id  : transaction_id,
        called_ids : calledIds
    }
    var base_url = $j('base').attr("href");
    var link = "<?php echo getUrl('display/refreshPage');?>";
    $j.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            if(msg.reply == 'success'){
                if(msg.html != lastHtml){

                    $j('#queue_board').html(msg.html);
                    lastHtml = msg.html;

                }

                if(msg.play_sound == "yes"){
                    var audio = new Audio('<?php echo getSkinCommonUrl('audio/doorbell-2.mp3'); ?>');
                    if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
          }else{
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0
          }


                }


                calledIds = msg.called_ids;

            }
            setTimeout(refreshPage, 1000);
        },
        error: function(a,b){
            setTimeout(refreshPage, 2000);
        }

    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call only one instance of Audio then play it when you need it.

At the very top of your code (above function RefreshPage) :

```
var audio = new Audio('<?php echo getSkinCommonUrl('audio/doorbell-2.mp3'); ?>');
```

Then in your ajax call :

```
if(msg.reply == 'success'){
            if(msg.html != lastHtml){

                $j('#queue_board').html(msg.html);
                lastHtml = msg.html;

            }

            if(msg.play_sound == "yes"){
               audio.pause();
               audio.play();
            }
```

I don't think you need other condition about if (audio.paused) etc... you can just play it just right after the pause.

Comment: hi sir, i havent tried that...whats with it if i implement that scenario?

Comment: That's a lot of audioInstances.  Do you need more than 1?

Comment: "No" because it was a display with a sound notification.

here is the other code reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44317737/codeigniter-session-still-exceeding-its-limit-of-4kb

Comment: Ha so, why don't you just call your bell sound only when the msg or number has change ? you don't need to create a new Audio each time.

Comment: do you have a sample ? you have a good point on that...@jacman

Comment: ow i see..so rather than make another instance of audio i would declare it as global right?

Comment: Yes, because in your current code you a creating a new one each time, but with the same file.

Comment: so basically it can prevent me from a random audio loop play? that unable to clear but rather by clearing the cookies...

Comment: You prevent a loop play because i added an audio.pause() before each .play(), so it will stop the audio before playing it each time.

Comment: oh great...will give it a shot....and posted as answer upon test cycle..